# Can't save new-alias even if i made ps1 file

Tags: powershell, alias

i've used command:

```
Get-Variable profile | Format-List
```

i did it for check where is my powershell profile folder.
After i did it it showed me this path:

```
C:\Users\Dom\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShellISE_profile.ps1
```

I opened this path and file named `Microsoft.PowerShellISE_profile.ps1` where i've saved my alias with command: `New-Alias rc Restart-Computer` but this alias doesn't work.. Powershell act like this file never existed.. Any suggestions?

Comment: You know that you have to start a new PowerShell session/ISE to take the new alias into effect? Also this is only one of the possible 6 profiles? See `$profile|Select *`

Comment: When i use command: "$profile|Select *" it shows me this: AllUsersAllHosts       : C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\profile.ps1
AllUsersCurrentHost    : C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Microsoft.PowerShellISE_profile.ps1
CurrentUserAllHosts    : C:\Users\Dom\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1
CurrentUserCurrentHost : C:\Users\Dom\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShellISE_profile.ps1
Length                 : 76 

Where should i save my new-alias so it work even if i close my powrshell? 
Thank you for help! :)

Comment: Well the names of the profiles speak for themselfes, choose the appropriate one. I'll add an answer to search through the profiles of the current host. Please add information by editing your question. Comments have no line breaks making reading lengthy text difficult.

Answer (score 1):

This script will look for `$Search` through the 4 profiles for the current host and print the finds with 4 lines of context:

```
## Search-PSProfiles.ps1
$ProfileNames = $PROFILE | Get-Member -MemberType noteproperty | select -Expandproperty Name
$Search = 'Restart'
ForEach ($Prof in $ProfileNames){
  $ThisProfile = $Profile."$Prof"
  if (Test-Path $ThisProfile){
  "{0,25} search for $Search in $ThisProfile " -f "`$Profile.$Prof" 
    Get-Content $ThisProfile|Select-String -AllMatches $Search -Context 0,4
  } else {
  "{0,25} doesn't exist ({1})" -f "`$Profile.$Prof",$ThisProfile
  }
}
```

Sample output started from a PoSh console:

```
$Profile.AllUsersAllHosts doesn't exist (C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\profile.ps1)
$Profile.AllUsersCurrentHost doesn't exist (C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1)
$Profile.CurrentUserAllHosts search for restart in C:\Users\UserName\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1

> New-Alias rc Restart-Computer
$Profile.CurrentUserCurrentHost search for restart in C:\Users\UserName\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1
```

Comment: It's really weird because when i try your script i get this output: <br>  
`$Profile.AllUsersAllHosts doesn't exist (C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\profile.ps1)
$Profile.AllUsersCurrentHost doesn't exist (C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Microsoft.PowerShellISE
_profile.ps1)
$Profile.CurrentUserAllHosts doesn't exist (C:\Users\Dom\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1)
$Profile.CurrentUserCurrentHost doesn't exist (C:\Users\Dom\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShellIS
E_profile.ps1)` <br>

Any suggestions what am i doing wrong? <br>

Comment: Looks like none of the profiles exist, what editor did you use? Take care the editor doesn't append an extesnion like `.txt`

Comment: I've used notepad... Maybe that's why it doesn't work.. 
I'll check it now, and tell you if changing editor helped.

Comment: 'New-Alias rc Restart-Computer' >> "$Env:Userprofile\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShellISE_profile.ps1" should suffice. No editor needed.

Comment: `"New-Alias rc Restart-Computer" >> $profile` should also do the trick.